# How clear System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache of a running Windows service without stopping the service?

Tags: .net, caching, service, memorycache

I have a service in which I'd like to use MemoryCache, however, one of my requirements is that I need to be able to clear said MemoryCache manually, without stopping the service.

Currently we're using the CacheManager from the Enterprise Library (Using Isolated Store, so I think it's in memory, then dumps to file when needed), and we clear the cache manually by deleting the files.  Any ideas on how I may do something similar, using the new cache libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your current cache using Enterprise Library has a file system dependency.  You can do the same thing with MemoryCache by associating a [HostFileChangeMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.hostfilechangemonitor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with each cache item.  When the monitored file(s) change on disk, the cache items will be purged.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to clear cache outside your service because it is bound to the AppDomain. You need to implement by yourself a entry point for clearing the cache.

After that, Simply [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.dispose.aspx) the memory cache and create a new one.